# ¿Cómo hago que un div no interfiera con el contenido de atrás?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

** Hola compas, necesito su ayuda **
Estuve jugando con `css` y en eso se me ocurrió esta idea de poner una capa que invierta los colores de otra, pero cuando intento interactuar con el contenido de atrás no puedo por el `z-index`, quiero saber cómo se puede hacer que el `div` que está por delante no impida la interacción con lo de atrás.

El código es un ejemplo de lo que les hablo, la parte de abajo sí se puede presionar el botón, en cambio la parte de arriba con la capa que invierte los colores no, porque está encima.

```css
.ctn{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  background:white;
}
.negative-cap{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  z-index:10;
  height:50vh;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

button{
  background:white;
  padding:10px 20px 7px;
  border-radius:20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctn">
  <div class="negative-cap"/></div>
  <button>HOLA</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes agregar `pointer-events: none;` a tu `negative-cap` y va a funcionar como deseas, te dejo el ejemplo funcionando

```css
.ctn{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  background:white;
}
.negative-cap{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  z-index:10;
  height:50vh;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
}

button{
  background:white;
  padding:10px 20px 7px;
  border-radius:20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctn">
  <div class="negative-cap"/></div>
  <button>HOLA</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, estaba buscando y me salian cosas que ni al caso, gracias por el dataso.

Comment: @zyx Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.